How can I use a Spring profile when using @SpringBootTest?
In a Spring Boot app, I have this service:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Foo {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:}")
    private String activeProfile;

    public boolean stuff() {
        System.out.println("Active profile: " + activeProfile);
        return true;
    }
}

When I start the app with -Dspring.profiles.active=bar, and call the method stuff(), the log displays Active profile: bar, as expected.
I have a sample test class that looks like this :
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("foo")
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    void fooTest() {
        assertTrue(foo.stuff());
    }
}

When I run this test, the log displays no active profile (Active profile : ).
Why @ActiveProfiles("foo") doesn't work in that case ?
My final goal is that some of my SpringBootTest classes go through some code, while others don't, without adding a boolean test method param.
Spring Boot version is 3.3.2

The problem is because of the order of Spring application lifecycle: active profiles are applied later than the injection of values into @Value annotated fields.
You can get these profiles from Environment, so you can change your service class to this:
   @Service
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class Foo {

    private final Environment env;

    public boolean stuff() {
        String[] activeProfiles = env.getActiveProfiles();
        System.out.println("Active profiles: " + String.join(", ", activeProfiles));
        return true;
    }
}

Note, that test class is unchanged.

Works nicely, thanks.

I have ran the above test and I can able to see the profile it ran as expected 'food'.


How comes that you launch the test with the profile food, and the Active profile logs foo ?
